# Exchange data between React Native Apps

Tags: react-native

I am currently developing two apps using React Native and App A stores user details like username,preferred language using Asyncstorage. Now i need to access these details when user opens App B i know we cannot achieve this through AsyncStorage as they are not shared across apps.But is there a way to do it.

[image: This is what i need to achieve]

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

1. Use your server. It is the only simple way to share data with multiple applications in react-native.
2. Handle more setting values for iOS and Android each.

   - [Adding an App to an App Group](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19) in iOS.
   - Use File component or Intent component in Android. [Link](https://medium.com/sketchware/sharing-data-74f02ddf37d0)
   - Split code for iOS and Android.

## Why?

Unfortunately, there is no way to get database from other applications in iOS. And query parameter would be ignored according to [Apple Universal Link Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

> Note that only the path component of the URL is used for comparison.
>   Other components, such as the query string or fragment identifier, are
>   ignored.

Thus, if you want to give your database information to another application without network, you need to handle more setting value for sharing contents with other applications in iOS and Android each. and split code. 
And you may use native code.

Comment: Thanks for the info so all companies like google,facebook,Uber that has multiple apps but single sign on ,so do through server....

Comment: @anbuselvan yup. that is the easy and simple way. :) And do not forget selecting answers in your other questions for people whose give helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-send-intent

```
npm i react-native-send-intent


SendIntentAndroid.isAppInstalled("com.facturationandroid").then(isInstalled => {
    SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.facturationandroid', 
     {"data1": "hello", "data2": "test"}).then((wasOpened) => {});
  });
```

Check the documentation for more information