# React-native get data from other application

Tags: react-native

Is ti possible to exchange data between react-native and others apps?
I found Linking, but it only can send data to other application, I also want to get data back.

Zlaja

Comment: Can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398411/exchange-data-between-react-native-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest some sort of Real-Time DB such as : https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/

"Realtime syncing makes it easy for your users to access their data from any device: web or mobile, and it helps your users collaborate with one another."

Comment: Ok, anyway communication with server should be used.